# Trouble rendering my variables to my view

Tags: laravel

For some reason I can't seem to render these variables to my index.
Here is my code on my SellerController.

```
public function index()
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $product = Product::where('user_id', $id);

    return view('seller.index', compact('product','id'));
}
```

and here is my code on my view

```
<ul>
     @foreach($product as $p)
      <li>
            <p>{{ $p->description }}</p>
            <p>{{ $p->price }}</p>
      </li>

     @endforeach
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

**1)** You need to update your `controller` function like:

```
public function index()
  {
    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    $product = Product::where('user_id', $id)->get();

      return view('seller.index', compact('product','id'));
  }
```

**OR**

**2)** You need to update your view file like:

```
    <ul>
        @foreach($product->get() as $p)
        <li>


        <p>{{ $p->description }}</p>
        <p>{{ $p->price }}</p>
      </li>

        @endforeach
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `get()` to execute the query:

```
$products = Product::where('user_id', $id)->get();
```

And you don't need to pass `$id` to a view since you can just use `auth()->id()` directly in the view to get currently authenticated user ID.